# javascript document.body is undefined - but, only WaterFox Webrobwsers

Tags: javascript

Until a long time ago (still in July) the script was fully functional. Now it broke down and I do not understand why:
I used it on the Waterfox browser based on the FireFox engine

script:

```
 function patrzpoczatek(str1, str2, n) {
  str1 = str1.substring(0, n);
  str2 = str2.substring(0, n);
  return str1 == str2;
}
var zatrzymaj = 0;

    function rozwijajResztePrzeszkadzajacychRzeczy() {
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        //var tab = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        //var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("_5v47");
        var tab = document.querySelectorAll('._5v47.fss');
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab) {
            if(i % 100 == 0) console.log("jestem na "+i+" pos");
            try { // omin zlosliwy link "Zobacz wiecej wydarzen"
                //if(tab[i].href == null || tab[i].href.length < 5)
                tab[i].click();
                ile++;
            } catch(err) { }
        }
        console.log("rozwijajResztePrzeszkadzajacychRzeczy: WYKONALEM "+ile+" clickow");    
        window.alert("BACKUP GOTOWY! No, prawie. Tera to se kopiuj.");
    }
    function rozwijajZobaczWiecejKomentarzy() {
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        // to tez do "Zobacz wczesniejsze komentarze"
        var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("UFIPagerLink");
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab)
                try {
                   tab[i].click();
                    ile++;
                } catch(err) { }
        console.log("rozwijajZobaczWiecejKomentarzy: WYKONALEM "+ile+" clickow");
        if(ile > 0)
        {
        // rozwijaj dopoki sie da
            setTimeout(rozwijajZobaczWiecejKomentarzy, 2000);
        } 
        else
        {
            setTimeout(rozwijajResztePrzeszkadzajacychRzeczy, 1000);
        }
    }
    function rozwijajZobaczWiecej() {
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("see_more_link");
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab) {
                try {
                   if(tab[i].onclick != null) {
                        ile++;
                        tab[i].onclick();
                    }
                } catch(err) { }
        }
        console.log("rozwijajZobaczWiecej: WYKONALEM "+ile+" clickow");
        setTimeout(rozwijajZobaczWiecejKomentarzy, 1000);
    }
    // na poczatku trzeba w ogole otworzyc komentarze, bo sa schowane
    function otworzKomentarze() {
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("UFIBlingBox");
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab)
                try {
                   tab[i].click();
                    ile++;
                } catch(err) { }
        console.log("otworzKomentarze: WYKONALEM "+ile+" clickow");
        /*if(ile > 0)
        {
        // rozwijaj dopoki sie da
            setTimeout(otworzKomentarze, 2000);
        } 
        else*/
    ////    {
                setTimeout(rozwijajZobaczWiecej, 1000);
        ///}
    }
    var popWys = 0;
    function scrollowanie() {
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }

                var tab = document.querySelectorAll('._5v47.fss');
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab) {
            if(i % 100 == 0) console.log("jestem na "+i+" pos");
            try { // omin zlosliwy link "Zobacz wiecej wydarzen"
                //if(tab[i].href == null || tab[i].href.length < 5)
                tab[i].click();
                ile++;
            } catch(err) { }
        }


        // to tez do "Zobacz wczesniejsze komentarze"
        var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("UFIPagerLink");
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab)
        {
                try {
                   tab[i].click();
                    ile++;
                } catch(err) { 
                }
        }
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("see_more_link");
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab) {
                try {
                   if(tab[i].onclick != null) {
                        ile++;
                        tab[i].onclick();
                    }
                } catch(err) { }
        }
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("UFIBlingBox");
        var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab)
        {
                try {
                   tab[i].click();
                    ile++;
                } catch(err) { }
        }

        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
  // to tez do "Zobacz wczesniejsze komentarze"
  var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("UFIReplySocialSentenceLinkText UFIReplySocialSentenceVerified");
      ///  var ile = 0;
        for (var i in tab)
                try {
                   tab[i].click();
            ///        ile++;
                } catch(err) { }
       /// console.log("rozwijajNOdpowiedz: WYKONALEM "+ile+" clickow");


        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        if(popWys != document.body.scrollHeight) {
            popWys = document.body.scrollHeight;
        if(zatrzymaj!=0)
        {
            console.log("Proces zostal zabity");
            return;
        }
            setTimeout(scrollowanie, 10000); // w razie czego zwiekszyc
        } else setTimeout(otworzKomentarze, 1000);
    }
    setTimeout(scrollowanie, 10000);
```

Now on WaterFox crashes:

TypeError: document.body is undefined [Learn More]

And the error leads to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected type

On Chrome, it opens up, but:

1. He does not open everything
2. Closes too early
3. After a few openings, he kills the Chrome process - Chrome crashes with a catastrophic error and everything is lost ... :(

Does anyone have an idea what has changed here, that it does not work anymore?

I use the browser console to run the script

Comment: *"I use the browser console to run the script"* How, specifically? It sounds like you're not waiting for the page to fully load before doing so, hence the chaotic results on Chrome.

Comment: I click ctrl + alt + j. Works in FireFox, WaterFox, Chrome

Comment: this is how it looks: https://zapodaj.net/f7194303bcfa4.png.html