# Stop the running script

Tags: javascript

I run a script in the browser that scrolls the page down. I run it from the browser console (ctrl + shift + j).

```
var popWys = 0;
    var terazWys = 0;
    var proba = 0;
    function scrollowanie() {
        if(popWys == document.body.scrollHeight)
        {
            proba++;
            if(proba > 10)
            {
                window.alert("To juz chyba wszystko, w razie czego odpal ponownie.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            proba = 0;
        }
        popWys = document.body.scrollTop;
        terazWys += 1000;
        window.scrollTo(0,terazWys);

        setTimeout(scrollowanie, 100);
    }
    setTimeout(scrollowanie, 100);
```

Question. How to stop it at any time from the command line? Can I write something, press to stop? Sam will never stop and blocks the browser. I tried with different: return; break; Stop. anything and nothing works.

Can it be done at all?

Comment: I want to stop scrolling the page down, thereby the entire script

Comment: Refresh the page.

Comment: in this way I would like to stop the execution of the script
 --> https://zapodaj.net/e6a47193ea1aa.png.html

Comment: refresh not, because then the result of the script will be lost - and I want to keep this result.

Comment: `if (terazWys >= 0) { setTimeout(scrollowanie, 100); }` and then in the console `terazWys = -1001`

Comment: Oh, it works! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearTimeout([variable name])` to stop the `setTimeout(scrollowanie, 100);`

Just assign `setTimeout(scrollowanie, 100);` to global variable like following:

```
globalVar = setTimeout(scrollowanie, 100);
```

And in the console type `clearTimeout(globalVar)` and the execution will finish

Comment: Ok thanks :) Or maybe you'll also help in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295904/javascript-document-body-is-undefined-but-only-waterfox-webrobwsers?noredirect=1#comment91539642_52295904

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap desired behaviour in an object that handles the process.

e.g.:

```
var script = (function () {
  var timeout;
  var DESIRED_TIME = 100;

  function scrollowanie() {
    console.log('::Testing');

    // Desired behaviour here

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(scrollowanie, DESIRED_TIME)
  }

  return {
    start: function() {
      timeout = setTimeout(scrollowanie, DESIRED_TIME);
    },
    stop: function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }
})();
```

Then in the command line you will just need to start the process

`script.start();`

and to end it

`script.stop();`

Comment: Ok thanks :) Or maybe you'll also help in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295904/javascript-document-body-is-undefined-but-only-waterfox-webrobwsers?noredirect=1#comment91539642_52295904